# Why is it best to NOT load up the file system of your application with content in a production scenario for spring web apps?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, image-uploading

On the guide of [spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) on uploading files there is this warning:

> In a production scenario, you more likely would store the files in a temporary location, a database, or perhaps a NoSQL store like Mongo’s GridFS. It’s is best to NOT load up the file system of your application with content.

without any other context. is this for reasons of security or performance or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the file system is most of the time not an appropriate location to store data:

- if your application is clustered, each machine will have its own file system, and a request to machine A thus won't see what has been stored on the file system by a previous request on machine B
- if your application is deployed on a PAAS in the cloud, providing horizontal scalability, the PAAS could start new VMs or containers to sustain the load, and then drop those VMs and containers, thus losing all the stuff you might have put on the file system
- some platforms don't even let you access the file system
- you probably already have a backup strategy for your database, or are relying on external storage services to provide one for you. Storing data on the file system would force you to provide another backup strategy